# Nginx not responding to remote IP

Tags: apache, nginx, firewall, port

I just installed Nginx listening on 8083 I can get a HTTP response when sending a HTTP request from the local machine.

eg:

```
curl -i localhost:8083
```

However, when I do the same from a remote machine, it just hangs until the ssh times out, or when the browser times out if accessed from the browser.

I pretty much have the default config:

```
user  apache apache;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8083;
        server_name  _;

        charset utf-8;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.php;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }
    }


}
```

any ideas?

Here is what I get for iptables -L

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

How would I know if it had a non-distribution firewall installed?

Comment: Do you have firewall installed on the server?

Comment: I added the info from iptables to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted hosting support and there is a hardware firewall outside the server preventing the port from being reached from remote IPs.